# curl ping URL from database and post up time on web page

Tags: php, curl, mysqli

So I'm currently trying to ping urls in a db table that should then post the `'LIVE'` or `'DOWN'` status of that url on a web page if the ping was successful, Before I tried it this way I had it set up as a php array with `fsocket` which worked.

Currently when I use the code as shown below it does pull the data from the db table but the badge showing `'LIVE'` or `'DOWN'` constantly shows `'DOWN'`.

```
<?php
require_once "config/config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM deployments";
 if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Server</th>";
  echo "<th>Deployment</th>";
  echo "<th>URL</th>";
  echo "<th>Status</th>";
  echo "<th>Port</th>";
  echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['server'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>";
   $url = $row['url'];
   $port = $row['port'];
   $url = '$url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if (200==$retcode) {
  echo "<td><span class='badge badge-success'>LIVE</span></td>";
} else {
  echo "<td><span class='badge badge-danger'>DOWN</span></td>";
}
  echo "<td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
  echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} else{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$url='$url';

That line shouldn't be in there. And if it is in there it needs to be double quotes to work.

Single quotes and double quotes work very differently in php. Having a $variable wont work as you're expecting if it's surrounded by single quotes.

```
<?php
//Example of how php treats a string in double quotes
$strFirstName="John";
echo "$strFirstName";

?>

<?php
//Example of how php treats a string in single quotes
$strFirstName="John";
echo '$strFirstName';

?>
```

The first example will work as expected, but the second one will literally output '$strFirstName' instead of 'John'

Comment: I would say that line `$url = "$url";` is not necessary at all conserning provided example by OP. Reason behind this is that OP already assigned this var `$url = $row['url'];` - so re-assgning has no place there. Converting it to sting can be done by `$url = "$row['url']";`  if that is needed at all. But your solution is valid =)

Answer (score 0):

As you simply need to determine if a particular url is active or not I'd be tempted to use `get_headers` ~ it's pretty quick

```
$url='https://www.google.com';
$headers = get_headers( $url, 1 );
$active = !empty( $headers );
if( $active ){/* do stuff */}
```

Or, put it in a function

```
function get_status( $url ){
    $headers = @get_headers( $url, 1 );
    return !empty( $headers );
}

$url = 'http://www.holycatflap.com';

$status = get_status( $url ) ? sprintf( '"%s" is UP!',$url ) : sprintf( '"%s" DOWN',$url );
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", $status );
```

outputs:

```
"http://www.holycatflap.com" DOWN
```

Comment: I've tried this, thank you for your reply!  but it's currently still showing all urls as `'DOWN'`

Comment: could you share one of the urls ?